# deinterlace png in php

Tags: php, gd

I try to deinterlace a png picture using php functions.

I found somewhere tips which leaded to this solution:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("interlaced.png");

imageinterlace($img, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0,0,0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
imagepng($img, "deinterlaced.png");
```

Unfortunately, this will not only keep the transparent areas, but extend them when the picture uses somewhere real black.

Is there another possibility to deinterlace without using imagecolorallocate?

I already tried using imagesavealpha, but it didn't work, or I used it wrong:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("interlaced.png");

imagealphablending($png, false);
imagesavealpha($png, true);

imageinterlace($img, 0);
imagepng($img, "deinterlaced.png");
```

This causes all transparent areas to be black (this is probably the reason, why I chose back then rgb0,0,0 in imagecolortransparent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second code block would work fine but for a small mistake; `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` are passed the incorrect resource, i.e., `$png` instead of `$img`.

Corrected code:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("interlaced.png");

imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

imageinterlace($img, 0);
imagepng($img, "deinterlaced.png");
```

Comment: How annoying, that I didn't see that. Just a stupid copy & paste mistake. Thanks for pointing out, that I was so close to the solution.